# Image not showing (broken image) but search works

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, image, searchable

i'm new in programming and have been working on a searchable database which can retrieve images by typing in keywords and after pressing submit will show results and the picture.

But so far i have no luck in getting the picture to show(broken link/image) but my search form does work and does correctly retrieve the name or result.

My table in phpmyadmin name is **shoes** , and i have 3 columns, 1 id (int15 PRI) ,2 brand/model (varchar 50), 3 picture (longblob).

My code is relative simple and hope you can help me out =)

**File name: search.php**

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
Name: <input type ="text" name="search_name"> <input type="submit" value="Search">

<?php
if (isset($_POST['search_name'])) {
    $search_name = $_POST['search_name'];

    if (!empty($search_name)){

        if (strlen($search_name)>=3) {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `shoes` WHERE `brand/model` LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($search_name)."%'";
        $query_run = mysql_query($query);
        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

        if ($query_num_rows>=1) {
            echo $query_num_rows.' Results found:<br>';

            while ($query_row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {


                    $picture = $query_row['picture'];
                    echo "</br>";
                    echo $query_row ['brand/model'];
                    echo "</br>";
                    echo "</br>";
                    //header("content-type: image/jpeg");
                    echo "<img src=image.php?id=".$row['id']." width=300 height=200/>";
                    echo "</br>";



            }
        } else {
            echo 'No Results Found.';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Text field must be more than 3 characters.';
    }

} else {
    echo 'Text Field Cannot be Empty!';
}
}
?>
```

**i have a image.php here**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$conn){
    echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysql_select_db("phsdatabase");

if(!$db){
echo mysql_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$query = "SELECT `picture` FROM shoes where id='$id'";
$query_run = mysql_query("$query",$conn);

if($query_run){
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run);
$type = "Content-type: image/jpeg";
header($type);
echo $row['picture'];
} else {
echo mysql_error();
}
```

?>

**storeinfo.php** to store new info,

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$conn)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
$db = mysql_select_db("phsdatabase",$conn);
if(!$db)
{
echo mysql_error();
}
@$brandmodel = $_POST['brand/model'];
@$picture = addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']));
@$image = getimagesize($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name']);//to know about image type etc

//$imgtype = $image['mime'];

if (isset($_POST['brand/model'])){
    $brandmodelentry = $_POST['brand/model'];

    if (!empty($brandmodelentry)){

        if (strlen($brandmodelentry)>=3) {
            $query ="INSERT INTO shoes VALUES('','$brandmodel','$picture')";
            $query_run = mysql_query($query,$conn);
            echo '<br>';
            echo "Information Stored Successfully!";

        } else {
            echo mysql_error();

        }
    echo '<br>';
    echo '<br>';
    echo "Thank you for Registering new information to our database!";
    } else{
        echo 'Text Field cannot be empty!';

    }

}
```

?>

**newentry.php which register new info**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="storeinfo.php" method="POST">


<center>Shoes Information</center>

Brand and Model Name<input type=text name="brand/model">

Picture of Shoes(Acceptable formats:<br>JPEG,JPG,PNG)<input type="file" name="picture" id ="picture">
<input type=submit name="submit" value="Store Information">
```

Comment: Your script image.php does not return any picture? Or what is your problem?

Comment: Hi, my image.php does return picture only if i put in the id. like image.php?id=1.  However on my search.php, the picture doesnt show together with my searches it shows a broken link

Comment: `$row['id']` ? not `$query_row['id']` ?

Comment: omg 5-T, thanks you so much!! the problem is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct except single line i.e.

```
echo "<img src=image.php?id=".$row['id']." width=300 height=200/>";
```

You have to change the line to :

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'
             .base64_encode($image['file_data']).'" width=300 height=200/>";
```

Comment: Hi vineet, thanks your prompt reply.. but i encountered a problem when i try to go to my search.php, it gave me an error 


    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'No' (T_STRING), expecting     ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\database\search.php on line 58
which is }
        } else {
            echo 'No Results Found.';
        }

Comment: @user3003490 here seems its correct and think this is not full code

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the problem my image was broken when I tried to display it from database is the the length of the image, I mean from the database where you put the length of a varchar you should change it to long text.

Answer (score -1):

Your image source should be image file extension not php extension, Please check :

```
echo "<img src='any jpg,png or gif exetension path' width='300' height='200' />";
```

for example:

```
echo "<img src='imagename.png' width='300' height='200' />";
```

Comment: Hi any advice on what should i change to? i been stuck for 2 days

Comment: actually your image source should be any image exetensional file like jpg,png or gif not php file.

Comment: Hi, i have a direct link, eg image.php?id=1 which can generate the image but i would like to like with the id instead of a static image.

Comment: you need iframe for that not image tag